# GAE DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-app-engine

I'm trying to move an existing webapp on GAE. At the moment the app is running on my local SDK.

When the app perform a compatibility check, it returns an error (read by FIREBUG ):
[image]

This is the code of the js who fails:

```
function checkConfig(){
    // Launch the configuration check procedure only if we can talk JSON
    // with the server side.
    install.sync(function(status, data){
        if (data.value.json == true){
            // Save useful information.
```

And here is another log:

```
GET http://localhost:13080/tao/api.php?type=Sync 200 OK


<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;C:\Users\arcot_000
\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\services/../../locales/da-DK/lang.rdf&quot; in <b>C:\Users\arcot_000
\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\utils\class.System.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;C:\Users\arcot_000
\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\services/../../locales/en-US/lang.rdf&quot; in <b>C:\Users\arcot_000
\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\utils\class.System.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;C:\Users\arcot_000
\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\services/../../locales/fr-FR/lang.rdf&quot; in <b>C:\Users\arcot_000
\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\utils\class.System.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;C:\Users\arcot_000
\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\services/../../locales/pt-PT/lang.rdf&quot; in <b>C:\Users\arcot_000
\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\utils\class.System.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;C:\Users\arcot_000
\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\services/../../locales/sv-SE/lang.rdf&quot; in <b>C:\Users\arcot_000
\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\utils\class.System.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users
\arcot_000\Desktop\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\utils\class.System.php:90) in <b>C:\Users\arcot_000\Desktop
\tao267\tao267v3\tao\install\api.php</b> on line <b>245</b><br />
{"type":"SyncReport","value":{"json":true,"rootURL":"https:\/\/localhost:13080\/tao\/api.php","availableDrivers"
:["pdo_mysql"],"availableLanguages":[],"availableTimezones":["Africa\/Abidjan","Africa\/Accra","Africa
\/Addis_Ababa","Africa\/Algiers","Africa\/Asmara","Africa\/Bamako","Africa\/Bangui","Africa\/Banjul"
,"Africa\/Bissau","Africa\/Blantyre","Africa\/Brazzaville","Africa\/Bujumbura","Africa\/Cairo","Africa
\/Casablanca","Africa\/Ceuta","Africa\/Conakry","Africa\/Dakar","Africa\/Dar_es_Salaam","Africa\/Djibouti"
,"Africa\/Douala","Africa\/El_Aaiun","Africa\/Freetown","Africa\/Gaborone","Africa\/Harare","Africa\
/Johannesburg","Africa\/Juba","Africa\/Kampala","Africa\/Khartoum","Africa\/Kigali","Africa\/Kinshasa"
,"Africa\/Lagos","Africa\/Libreville","Africa\/Lome","Africa\/Luanda","Africa\/Lubumbashi","Africa\/Lusaka"
,"Africa\/Malabo","Africa\/Maputo","Africa\/Maseru","Africa\/Mbabane","Africa\/Mogadishu","Africa\/Monrovia"
,"Africa\/Nairobi","Africa\/Ndjamena","Africa\/Niamey","Africa\/Nouakchott","Africa\/Ouagadougou","Africa
\/Porto-Novo","Africa\/Sao_Tome","Africa\/Tripoli","Africa\/Tunis","Africa\/Windhoek","America\/Adak"
,"America\/Anchorage","America\/Anguilla","America\/Antigua","America\/Araguaina","America\/Argentina
\/Buenos_Aires","America\/Argentina\/Catamarca","America\/Argentina\/Cordoba","America\/Argentina\/Jujuy"
,"America\/Argentina\/La_Rioja","America\/Argentina\/Mendoza","America\/Argentina\/Rio_Gallegos","America
\/Argentina\/Salta","America\/Argentina\/San_Juan","America\/Argentina\/San_Luis","America\/Argentina
\/Tucuman","America\/Argentina\/Ushuaia","America\/Aruba","America\/Asuncion","America\/Atikokan","America
\/Bahia","America\/Bahia_Banderas","America\/Barbados","America\/Belem","America\/Belize","America\/Blanc-Sablon"
,"America\/Boa_Vista","America\/Bogota","America\/Boise","America\/Cambridge_Bay","America\/Campo_Grande"
,"America\/Cancun","America\/Caracas","America\/Cayenne","America\/Cayman","America\/Chicago","America
\/Chihuahua","America\/Costa_Rica","America\/Creston","America\/Cuiaba","America\/Curacao","America\
/Danmarkshavn","America\/Dawson","America\/Dawson_Creek","America\/Denver","America\/Detroit","America
\/Dominica","America\/Edmonton","America\/Eirunepe","America\/El_Salvador","America\/Fortaleza","America
\/Glace_Bay","America\/Godthab","America\/Goose_Bay","America\/Grand_Turk","America\/Grenada","America
\/Guadeloupe","America\/Guatemala","America\/Guayaquil","America\/Guyana","America\/Halifax","America
\/Havana","America\/Hermosillo","America\/Indiana\/Indianapolis","America\/Indiana\/Knox","America\/Indiana
\/Marengo","America\/Indiana\/Petersburg","America\/Indiana\/Tell_City","America\/Indiana\/Vevay","America
\/Indiana\/Vincennes","America\/Indiana\/Winamac","America\/Inuvik","America\/Iqaluit","America\/Jamaica"
,"America\/Juneau","America\/Kentucky\/Louisville","America\/Kentucky\/Monticello","America\/Kralendijk"
,"America\/La_Paz","America\/Lima","America\/Los_Angeles","America\/Lower_Princes","America\/Maceio"
,"America\/Managua","America\/Manaus","America\/Marigot","America\/Martinique","America\/Matamoros","America
\/Mazatlan","America\/Menominee","America\/Merida","America\/Metlakatla","America\/Mexico_City","America
\/Miquelon","America\/Moncton","America\/Monterrey","America\/Montevideo","America\/Montserrat","America
\/Nassau","America\/New_York","America\/Nipigon","America\/Nome","America\/Noronha","America\/North_Dakota
\/Beulah","America\/North_Dakota\/Center","America\/North_Dakota\/New_Salem","America\/Ojinaga","America
\/Panama","America\/Pangnirtung","America\/Paramaribo","America\/Phoenix","America\/Port-au-Prince","America
\/Port_of_Spain","America\/Porto_Velho","America\/Puerto_Rico","America\/Rainy_River","America\/Rankin_Inlet"
,"America\/Recife","America\/Regina","America\/Resolute","America\/Rio_Branco","America\/Santa_Isabel"
,"America\/Santarem","America\/Santiago","America\/Santo_Domingo","America\/Sao_Paulo","America\/Scoresbysund"
,"America\/Sitka","America\/St_Barthelemy","America\/St_Johns","America\/St_Kitts","America\/St_Lucia"
,"America\/St_Thomas","America\/St_Vincent","America\/Swift_Current","America\/Tegucigalpa","America
\/Thule","America\/Thunder_Bay","America\/Tijuana","America\/Toronto","America\/Tortola","America\/Vancouver"
,"America\/Whitehorse","America\/Winnipeg","America\/Yakutat","America\/Yellowknife","Antarctica\/Casey"
,"Antarctica\/Davis","Antarctica\/DumontDUrville","Antarctica\/Macquarie","Antarctica\/Mawson","Antarctica
\/McMurdo","Antarctica\/Palmer","Antarctica\/Rothera","Antarctica\/Syowa","Antarctica\/Troll","Antarctica
\/Vostok","Arctic\/Longyearbyen","Asia\/Aden","Asia\/Almaty","Asia\/Amman","Asia\/Anadyr","Asia\/Aqtau"
,"Asia\/Aqtobe","Asia\/Ashgabat","Asia\/Baghdad","Asia\/Bahrain","Asia\/Baku","Asia\/Bangkok","Asia\
/Beirut","Asia\/Bishkek","Asia\/Brunei","Asia\/Chita","Asia\/Choibalsan","Asia\/Colombo","Asia\/Damascus"
,"Asia\/Dhaka","Asia\/Dili","Asia\/Dubai","Asia\/Dushanbe","Asia\/Gaza","Asia\/Hebron","Asia\/Ho_Chi_Minh"
,"Asia\/Hong_Kong","Asia\/Hovd","Asia\/Irkutsk","Asia\/Jakarta","Asia\/Jayapura","Asia\/Jerusalem","Asia
\/Kabul","Asia\/Kamchatka","Asia\/Karachi","Asia\/Kathmandu","Asia\/Khandyga","Asia\/Kolkata","Asia\
/Krasnoyarsk","Asia\/Kuala_Lumpur","Asia\/Kuching","Asia\/Kuwait","Asia\/Macau","Asia\/Magadan","Asia
\/Makassar","Asia\/Manila","Asia\/Muscat","Asia\/Nicosia","Asia\/Novokuznetsk","Asia\/Novosibirsk","Asia
\/Omsk","Asia\/Oral","Asia\/Phnom_Penh","Asia\/Pontianak","Asia\/Pyongyang","Asia\/Qatar","Asia\/Qyzylorda"
,"Asia\/Rangoon","Asia\/Riyadh","Asia\/Sakhalin","Asia\/Samarkand","Asia\/Seoul","Asia\/Shanghai","Asia
\/Singapore","Asia\/Srednekolymsk","Asia\/Taipei","Asia\/Tashkent","Asia\/Tbilisi","Asia\/Tehran","Asia
\/Thimphu","Asia\/Tokyo","Asia\/Ulaanbaatar","Asia\/Urumqi","Asia\/Ust-Nera","Asia\/Vientiane","Asia
\/Vladivostok","Asia\/Yakutsk","Asia\/Yekaterinburg","Asia\/Yerevan","Atlantic\/Azores","Atlantic\/Bermuda"
,"Atlantic\/Canary","Atlantic\/Cape_Verde","Atlantic\/Faroe","Atlantic\/Madeira","Atlantic\/Reykjavik"
,"Atlantic\/South_Georgia","Atlantic\/St_Helena","Atlantic\/Stanley","Australia\/Adelaide","Australia
\/Brisbane","Australia\/Broken_Hill","Australia\/Currie","Australia\/Darwin","Australia\/Eucla","Australia
\/Hobart","Australia\/Lindeman","Australia\/Lord_Howe","Australia\/Melbourne","Australia\/Perth","Australia
\/Sydney","Europe\/Amsterdam","Europe\/Andorra","Europe\/Athens","Europe\/Belgrade","Europe\/Berlin"
,"Europe\/Bratislava","Europe\/Brussels","Europe\/Bucharest","Europe\/Budapest","Europe\/Busingen","Europe
\/Chisinau","Europe\/Copenhagen","Europe\/Dublin","Europe\/Gibraltar","Europe\/Guernsey","Europe\/Helsinki"
,"Europe\/Isle_of_Man","Europe\/Istanbul","Europe\/Jersey","Europe\/Kaliningrad","Europe\/Kiev","Europe
\/Lisbon","Europe\/Ljubljana","Europe\/London","Europe\/Luxembourg","Europe\/Madrid","Europe\/Malta"
,"Europe\/Mariehamn","Europe\/Minsk","Europe\/Monaco","Europe\/Moscow","Europe\/Oslo","Europe\/Paris"
,"Europe\/Podgorica","Europe\/Prague","Europe\/Riga","Europe\/Rome","Europe\/Samara","Europe\/San_Marino"
,"Europe\/Sarajevo","Europe\/Simferopol","Europe\/Skopje","Europe\/Sofia","Europe\/Stockholm","Europe
\/Tallinn","Europe\/Tirane","Europe\/Uzhgorod","Europe\/Vaduz","Europe\/Vatican","Europe\/Vienna","Europe
\/Vilnius","Europe\/Volgograd","Europe\/Warsaw","Europe\/Zagreb","Europe\/Zaporozhye","Europe\/Zurich"
,"Indian\/Antananarivo","Indian\/Chagos","Indian\/Christmas","Indian\/Cocos","Indian\/Comoro","Indian
\/Kerguelen","Indian\/Mahe","Indian\/Maldives","Indian\/Mauritius","Indian\/Mayotte","Indian\/Reunion"
,"Pacific\/Apia","Pacific\/Auckland","Pacific\/Chatham","Pacific\/Chuuk","Pacific\/Easter","Pacific\
/Efate","Pacific\/Enderbury","Pacific\/Fakaofo","Pacific\/Fiji","Pacific\/Funafuti","Pacific\/Galapagos"
,"Pacific\/Gambier","Pacific\/Guadalcanal","Pacific\/Guam","Pacific\/Honolulu","Pacific\/Johnston","Pacific
\/Kiritimati","Pacific\/Kosrae","Pacific\/Kwajalein","Pacific\/Majuro","Pacific\/Marquesas","Pacific
\/Midway","Pacific\/Nauru","Pacific\/Niue","Pacific\/Norfolk","Pacific\/Noumea","Pacific\/Pago_Pago"
,"Pacific\/Palau","Pacific\/Pitcairn","Pacific\/Pohnpei","Pacific\/Port_Moresby","Pacific\/Rarotonga"
,"Pacific\/Saipan","Pacific\/Tahiti","Pacific\/Tarawa","Pacific\/Tongatapu","Pacific\/Wake","Pacific
\/Wallis","UTC"]}}
```

I need to config something for the JSON support?

Comment: Please don't add as an image what can be added as text. How can somebody reading your question on a mobile (say) see? Imagine that there is one person in the universe who can help you, and you have 5 seconds to tempt them to answer. Try to make it as easy for them as possible, or you will lose your chance. In some situations, this is pretty much the case.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit soon, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reason GAE disables external XML entity loading by default (See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Functions_that_may_be_manually_enabled for more details). You'll need to call `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false)` before loading the XML.

Comment: Thanks, I've read the doc. So I created the php.ini with the string:

google_app_engine.enable_functions = "libxml_disable_entity_loader"

Then I've added the call libxml_disable_entity_loader(false) inside the .js who call data variable but now I get the error:

ReferenceError: libxml_disable_entity_loader is not defined
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);

I wrote badly the php.ini?

Comment: libxml_disable_entity_loader should be called in your api.php, not in your javascript.